# Gitlab.com runners: How do I install and run software from an external repos?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm pretty new to Gitlab.com's CI and to docker.

I have a simple python pelican static blog that builds with a simple `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: python:2.7-alpine

pages:
  script:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - pelican -s publishconf.py
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
```

So I see that it specifies a python docker image, uses pip to install various python scripts, then runs pelican all within that image.

Now my issue is that I want to run a my own version of pelican. I modified my `requirements.txt` file to look for my own branch of pelican, but this fails

```
beautifulsoup4
markdown
smartypants
typogrify
git+https://github.com/jerryasher/pelican.git@hidden-cats
pelican-fontawesome
pelican-gist
pelican-jsfiddle
pelican-neighbors
```

Now when it builds, Gitlab's Runner tells me:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.9.0 (82714ae)
Using Docker executor with image python:2.7-alpine ...
Pulling docker image python:2.7-alpine ...
Running on runner-e11ae361-project-1654117-concurrent-0 via runner-e11ae361-machine-1484613050-ce975c76-digital-ocean-4gb...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/jerrya/ashercodes'...
Checking out 532f8b38 as master...
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting git+https://github.com/jerryasher/pelican.git@hidden-cats (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Cloning https://github.com/jerryasher/pelican.git (to hidden-cats) to /tmp/pip-72xxqt-build
  Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/jerryasher/pelican.git /tmp/pip-72xxqt-build
Cannot find command 'git'
ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

Okay,

Git doesn't seem to be present. Indeed prior to the above attempt, I had added a line (that failed) to the `.gitlab-ci.yml` script saying to use git to clone that repo locally, and that also failed, because ... no git.

(The docker image I am using `python:2.7-alpine` also seems to have no `apt-get`.)

Do I need to build my own docker image containing `git` and `python` and anything else that I require, or is there some "usual" way to have a Gitlab.com runner pull in an external program from either a git repo, or some typical linux package repository?

And if I can't do this, is that in this case the fault of the runner, or the fault of the docker image?

Answer (score 1):

You can just install git (and any other package) if you need it. Your own image will be faster but it's not needed.

```
pages:
  script:
    - apk --update add git openssh
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, for the moment I am using my own docker image, which was a fun adventure in its own right. I'll retry this using apk rather than apt-get. I think I would prefer using official docker images and then modifying them in the yml as needed.

Comment: @Jerry You're using an image based on alpine linux and so it doesn't have apt (or bash, or any other thing). python:2.7 image is based on Debian so it does offer tools you are more familiar with.